# Remove last set of value from a comma separated string in java

Tags: java

I wan to remove the last set of data from string using java.
For example I have a string like `A,B,C,` and I want to remove `,C,` and want to get the out put value like `A,B` . How is it possible in java? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String start = "A,B,C,";
String result = start.subString(0, start.lastIndexOf(',', start.lastIndexOf(',') - 1));
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a fairly "robust" reg-exp solution:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((\\w,?)+),\\w+,?");

for (String test : new String[] {"A,B,C", "A,B", "A,B,C,",
                                 "ABC,DEF,GHI,JKL"}) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
    if (m.matches())
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
A,B
A
A,B
ABC,DEF,GHI
```

Answer (score 2):

Since there may be a trailing comma, something like this (using org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils):

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(myString.split()));
list.remove(list.length-1);
myString = StringUtils.join(list, ",");
```

Comment: Surely doing the full split and join is massive overkill?

Comment: It depends on his case.  The code is simple and readable and does not prematurely optimize.  I like the regex solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String#lastIndexOf` to find the index of the second-to-last comma, and then [`String#substring`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)) to extract just the part before it. Since your sample data ends with a ",", you'll need to use [the version of `String#lastIndexOf` that accepts a starting point](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) and have it skip the last character (e.g., feed in the string's `length` minus 1).

I wasn't going to post *actual code* on the theory better to teach a man to fish, but as everyone else is:

```
String data = "A,B,C,";
String shortened = data.substring(0, data.lastIndexOf(',', data.length() - 2));
```

Comment: at the end(after C) I also have a comma.So when I want to get the lastIndexOf comma I will get the index of last comma that is comma after C.

Comment: @Suvonkar: I just noticed that and was updating as you were commenting; see the update.

Comment: @Peter: :-) Actually, I really read your comment that way at first. I didn't see the trailing comma thing until later.

Answer (score 0):

If full String.split() is not possible, the how about just scanning the string for comma and stop after reaching 2nd, without including it in final answer?

```
String start = "A,B";
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
int count = 0;
for(char ch:start.toCharArray()) {
    if(ch == ',') {
        count++;
        if(count==2) {
            break;
        }
    }
    result.append(ch);
}
System.out.println("Result = "+result.toString());
```

Simple trick, but should be efficient.

In case you want last set of data removed, irrespective of how much you want to read, then
`start.substring(0, start.lastIndexOf(',', start.lastIndexOf(',')-1))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do this

```
String start = "A,B,C,";
String result = start.replaceAll(",[^,]*,$", "");
System.out.println(result);
```

prints

```
A,B
```

This simply erases the the 'second last comma followed by data followed by last comma'

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is using a `StringTokenizer`:

```
  String input = "A,B,C,";
  StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input, ",");
  String output = new String();
  int tokenCount = tokenizer.countTokens();
  for (int i = 0; i < tokenCount - 1; i++) {
    output += tokenizer.nextToken();
    if (i < tokenCount - 1) {
      output += ",";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string RemoveLastSepratorFromString(string input)
{
    string result = input;
    if (result.Length > 1)
    {
        result = input.Remove(input.Length - 1, 1);
    }
    
    return result;
}
        
// use from above method
string test = "1,2,3,"
string strResult = RemoveLastSepratorFromString(test);
//output --> 1,2,3
```